# THREE.js Model-Loading Issues

Tags: three.js, 3d

I’m trying to load some 3D models from a remote URL into my page and I’m suddenly getting this error over and over again:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

The models I’m working with are those available from **THREE.js**’s GIT - [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/models/gltf) - so they’re all perfectly good legit models that we’ve all been using for years. In other words: they don't contain any `unexpected character` anywhere.

What’s weird is that during development of this project, I first just downloaded these models (the **".gltf"** and **".glb"** files) directly to my hard drive and loaded them into my page from there - and my code worked perfectly. But as soon as I uploaded these very same models to a remote server and tried to load them from that URL, I suddenly started getting this error.

Here’s my loading function:

```
function loadModel(modelFileName) {
   console.log("->In 'loadModel()', 'modelFileName' =", modelFileName);

   // Load the Object:
   gltfLoader.load(modelFileName, function(incomingScene) { 
      console.log(modelFileName, "' has arrived!!!");
      console.log("  =>'incomingScene' = ", incomingScene);

      let loadedScene = new THREE.Scene();
      loadedScene = incomingScene.scene;
                
      scene.add(loadedScene);
      const defaultTransform = new THREE.Matrix4()
          .multiply(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
      loadedScene.applyMatrix4(defaultTransform);
  },
  // Called when loading is in progresses:
  function(xhr) {
      console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
  },
  function(error) {
      console.log("ERROR! -->", error);
  });
}
```

Here’s the URL where one of the models I’m requesting is sitting:
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmYqwNYxqmu4z39emTo7h9D62rbwm1esAmbAf2PctAyUvu?filename=Flamingo.glb

(This particular model was actually loading just fine when I ran the app/page the first couple of times - but then it suddenly stopped loading and gave me that error I listed up top. Makes no sense.)

The only output I'm getting from the browser's JS Console regarding all this is from the progress callback bit of the code I posted above, which just says:

```
 Infinity% loaded
```

Any ideas what’s causing this - and how it can be solved?

==================================================

UPDATE:

here's a screenshot of the NETWORK tab in the my browser:

[image]

Comment: What is your Network tab showing in the Devtools? It's probably returning an HTML file with `<elements>` instead of a JSON object.

Comment: @Marquizzo  Hey you're right! It's showing me that my model is coming in as an HTML file. How's that possible?  And more importantly, what needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: Read the HTML file, see what it's telling you.

Comment: How? I don't see an actual HTML file, I just see a whole list of files that have been downloaded/fetched when my page loaded - things like `jQuery` and other dependencies , but I don't see a FILE per se.

Comment: I just added a screen grab of what my NETWORK tab is showing.  You can see the file titled "QmauYb...." - that's part of the URL where my `.GLB`  model file is sitting, and on the right side you see it's listed as an HTML file, even though it's a `.GLB` file.